# NULL values in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, null

i've got a table "bla" like this:

```
[id]    [name]    [fk]
1       test      4
2       foo       5
3       bar       NULL
```

if i do the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE fk <> 4
```

i only get the record with the id 2. i don't get the record with id 3 where fk is null.
I thought NULL != 4. Seems that this is wrong.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`NULL` doesn't compare equal to anything. You'll need to accept nulls explicitly:

```
where fk <> 4 or fk is null;
```

See [Working with NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for more information about `NULL` handling.

Answer (score 4):

Because `NULL` stands for `UNKNOWN`, and when you compare a value with `UNKNOWN`, the result will always be false.

Take a look at this comparisons -

```
NULL = NULL    -- false, since both are unknown, so the truth value of this expression can't be determined.
NULL = 4       -- false
4 = 4          -- true, since both values are known.
```

If you want to fetch the records containing `NULL`, you need to re-write your query this way -

```
where fk <> 4
OR fk is null;
```

For more information, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)).

Answer (score 3):

NULL is not a value, but rather the unknown absence of a value. If you'd like to test for NULL, you have to do so explicitly by using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. For example, NULL will test **FALSE** even against NULL itself. So, [working with NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) is only done with the aforementioned functions (and `ISNULL()`). Your query could be rewritten as

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE fk <> 4 OR fk IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is special in that it represents an "unknown" value. This can't be compared to numbers (or any other value for that matter), hence the result -

Is `NULL` <> 4? The answer is - don't know. Is 4 different from an unknown value?

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE fk <> 4 OR FK IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE NOT (fk = 4)
```

Logic:

```
NULL = 4 --false
5 = 4    --false
4 = 4    --true

NOT (NULL = 4) --true
NOT (5 = 4)    --true
NOT (4 = 4)    --false
```

Answer (score 0):

Following statement should help:

SELECT * FROM bla WHERE COALESCE(fk,0) <> 4