# MySql rows with NULL values are not retriving in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a strange issue with a simple select query and unable to find what is happening. I am using below sql to fetch some records from a customer table. My query is as follows.

```
SELECT `C`.* FROM `customers` AS `C` WHERE `C`.`typeId`!=9 ORDER BY C.name ASC
```

My table structure is as follows

```
|id|name|typeId|
|1 |abc |1     |
|2 |abcd|9     |
|3 |xxxx|NULL  |
|4 |qwe |NULL  |
|5 |xvf |10    |
```

in the above table, typeId is an integer field and default NULL. Database is MySql

When I am executing the above mentiond SQL, I am getting all other rows except typeId=9 and typeId = NULL. My question is why typeId=NULL is getting omitted from the result? I have googled a lot and unable to find any answer. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try out this...

```
SELECT `C`.* 
FROM `customers` AS `C` 
WHERE `C`.`typeId`!=9 
   OR `C`.`typeId` IS NULL 
ORDER BY C.name ASC
```

Comment: This one is working. So this means i have to add an explicit or condition in every case?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> SELECT `C`.* FROM `customers` AS `C` WHERE `C`.`typeId`!=9 OR `C`.`typeId` IS  NULL ORDER BY C.name ASC

Answer (score 2):

Because NULL is equivalent to UNKNOWN, and when you compare a value with UNKNOWN, the result will always be **false**.

If you want to fetch the records containing NULL, you need to re-write your query this way -

```
where `C`.`typeId` <> 9
OR `C`.`typeId` is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL doesn't compare equal to anything. You'll need to accept nulls explicitly: Just add

```
AND C.typeId IS NOT NULL
```

in the query also

see the NULL working over here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Check the below question too :- [NULL values in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827010/null-values-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       COALESE(typeId,0) AS type
FROM customers AS C 
WHERE C.type!=9  
ORDER BY C.name ASC
```

Comment: This one also ignores the NULL rows