# SQL: What's the difference between '=' and 'is'?

Tags: sql

When I check if a value is NULL I usually use '=', 
This doesn't work somehow but 'is null' works. 
Why's that? What is  the difference?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827010/null-values-in-where-clause

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822154/standard-sql-boolean-operator-is-vs-equals-operator

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Think of null as a 'state' of the cell not as a 'content value'.

Comment: [take a look here this is one similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE myvalue = null
```

will never be true.  Since even if "myvalue" is undefined ("null"), the database can't determine that it equals null (since null by definition means "unknown" and two "unknowns" can't be equal to each other).

```
WHERE myvalue IS null
```

is more straight-forward.  This checks whether "myvalue" is undefined (is "null" in database lingo).

Comment: Funny, thanks, I come from Java so it sounded reasonable to me that I check for NULL with '='...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at :
[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Basically, null can be thought of as no value or no value know.
A comparison operator (eg =) is effectively asking if an unknown or non existent value is equal to another unknown or non existent value.  The only sensible return in this case is another unknown or non existent value - null.

IS NULL asks is the value unknown or non existent - this can return either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

you can try the below code. THis is for SQL SEVER

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

DECLARE @VALUE INT =NULL
IF @VALUE=NULL
PRINT 'IN 1'
IF @VALUE IS NULL
PRINT 'IN 2'