# Unable to retrieve records using Spring Data JPA repository when foreign key is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue when I am searching an Entity and its records with a foreign key. As per the business logic, I need to search Entity - LookupRequest table with account (with not null account id) and foreign key = "callback" (with null).

Please note that account id is not unique (for simplicity I deleted other parameters in the table to make it short). Once I filter the record, I have to update LookupRequest.callBack to foreignkey entry. I am unable to retrieve the records when foreign key is null.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class LookupRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String account;

    @Column
    private String caseId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique=false, nullable=true, updatable=true)
    private Callback callback;

    public LookupRequest(String account, String caseId) {
        this.account = account;
        this.caseId = caseId;
        callback = null;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public String getCaseId() {
        return caseId;
    }

    public Callback getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

}


@Repository
public interface LookupRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<LookupRequest, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT lr from LookupRequest lr where lr.account = :account and lr.callback = :callback")
    LookupRequest findCaseId(@Param("account") String account, @Param("callback") String callback);
}    


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Callback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(length = 20000)
    private String rawResponse;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRawResponse(String rawResponse) {
        this.rawResponse = rawResponse;
    }

}
```

then I am calling as follows:

```
LookupRequest lookupRequestFromDB = lookupRequestRepository.findCaseId("ABC", null);
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NULL values in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827010/null-values-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL does not compare equal with anything, you need to use "is NULL".
See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#WHERE_Clause)

In your case:

```
SELECT lr from LookupRequest lr where lr.account = :account and (lr.callback = :callback or lr.callback is null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
However, when @JoinColumn is there then I can't search with null values. So I changed foreign key reference as below to search null values.

    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
    private Callback callback;

and changed jpa query to 
LookupRequest findTopByAccountAndCallbackIsNullOrderByCreatedAtAsc(String account);